# Can i get facebook friends that profile is public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

for users that their profile is public (no security) can i get their friend list without being a friend with them ?

Thanks

Comment: You should test this out with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  Find a public non-friend's  user_id and query `/user_id/friends`... See what you get back...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t get friends of just anyone.

Trying to do so with a random user id will get you an exception saying,

> *"(#604) Can't lookup all friends of $userid. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app."*